# Finding Substrings Between Nested Tags in Java

Tags: java, nested, substring, apache-stringutils

I'm working on a method that needs to parse a string representing a Type declaration into its constituent parts. So for example the string

```
"List<T extends Integer>"
```

would produce the following array:

```
["List", "T", "extends", "Integer"]
```

For simple cases like this, I can use the 'substringsBetween' method of the StringUtils class of apache-commons to find the part inside the tags. The problem I'm running into is that the substringsBetween method does not seem to be able to handle nested tags. If I make the following call:

```
StringUtils.substringsBetween("HashSet<ArrayList<T extends Integer>>", "<", ">");
```

I end up with a result of:

```
["ArrayList<T extends Integer"]
```

Is there some way to do this using apache commons, or will I need to parse the string by hand? If I need to parse it manually, is there a good example of an algorithm for doing this?

Comment: What is your expected answer for the case of nested tags? `T extends Integer`?

Comment: While you could probably hack at this, it really feels as if you're moving towards needing a fully-fledged parser. First split into tokens `[ "List",
 "<", "T", "extends",  "Integer", ">" ]` then step through the tokens moving through a state machine, to build a parse tree. It's too big a subject for a SO answer, but try: https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-java/

Comment: Look at `StreamTokenizer` for the first step.

Comment: @slim some of those parsers look promising. I was hoping I wouldn't have to go that route, but hopefully I can find something lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the space and change the character bracket to be ignored.

For example....

```
    String example = "List<T extends Integer>";
    example = example.replace('<', ' ').replace('>', ' ');
    String[] word = example.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i< word.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(word[i]+" ");
    }
```

If you want inner bracket to have the same behavior you can do the same just parse a unique character in a string.

```
String exampleTwo ="HashSet<ArrayList<T extends Integer>>";
exampleTwo = exampleTwo.replace('<', '-').replace('>', '-');
String[] innerWord = exampleTwo.split("-");
for(int i=0; i< innerWord.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(innerWord[i]+" ");
}

//position is the same number of brackets
System.out.println(innerWord[0]); //HashSet
System.out.println(innerWord[1]); //ArrayList
System.out.println(innerWord[2]); //T extends Integer
```

Comment: The problem with simply replacing the brackets is that I loose the information about which parts of the string were which. I need to be handle the parts outside the brackets separately from the parts inside.

Comment: You are right, but this was just a general idea. You could split by "<" ">" and " " (brackets and spaces) and put them into a list, when you find the start split the list and get the index between the tokens. I mean there are many ways to do it. If you want to keep the bracket for debugging you can add an extra string before replacing it. (using substring position).